Resubmitting proof of income
In the state of TN, if a tenant is always late on rent, at the end of their lease before signing a new lease, can the landlord request proof of income?

Yes.
If the lease has no right to renew in it, the landlord can insist on anything prior to signing a new lease and is under no obligation to renew it at all.
